# Guardar en multiples bases de datos, nombres de bd cargados dinamicamente en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un proyecto de un sistema, quiero que guarde la informacion que introduzca cada usuario en una base de datos personal del usuario. En php hago esto:

```php
$bd = "bacoopco_".$_SESSION["bbdduser"];
$pass = "";
$user="root";

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $bd);

    if($mysqli->connect_error){

        die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);

    }
```

Donde `$bd = "bacoopco_".$_SESSION["bbdduser"];` es el nombre de la base de datos.
de esta manera actualmente puedo guardar en multiples bases de datos, pero estoy desarrollando este proyecto en laravel y no he logrado hacer el guardado de forma dinámica, ya intente con algo básico en el archivo `database.php` pero me da error por desconocer el metodo. asi lo intente:

```php
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
'connections'  => [

     'mysql'  => [
     'driver'     => 'mysql',
     'host'       => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
     'database'   => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
     'username'   => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
     'password'   => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
     'charset'    => 'utf8',
     'collation'  => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
     'prefix'     => '',
     'strict'     => false,
     ],

    ‘comments’  => [
    'driver'     => 'mysql',
    'host'       => env('COMMENTS_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'   => env('bacoopco_'.\Auth::user()->bbdduser, 'forge'),
    'username'   => env('COMMENTS_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'   => env('COMMETNS_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'    => 'utf8',
    'collation'  => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'     => '',
    'strict'     => false,
     ],
```

Si pudiesen ayudarme de antemano agradecido

Comment: No voy a meterme con tu problema (porque no se) pero guardar datos en multiples bases de datos, porque son de distintos usuarios, suena a problematico. Que pasa cuando tengas 100 usuarios y tengas que cambiar una columna en tu programa?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por comentar, la verdad tampoco veo conveniente el uso de tantas bases de datos, pero la persona que me solicita el proyecto lo pide, para guardar la bbdd de cada cliente a parte. Es un proyecto de facturación. Compras, ventas, inventario.

Comment: Y para eso estamos los desarrolladores.. para mostrar esas falencias.. si quisieras sacar las ventas totales de un producto, como podrias hacer query sin que tarde horas? si te pidieron esto, debes especificar que esta mal. No que no es conveniente. Esta mal y no se hace asi.

Comment: Es correcto. La otra parte que no comente al leer bien, es que la empresa piensa usar este sistema en ambiente web para brindarle el sistema de facturas a cada cliente. Me explico, trabajo en una oficina de informatica, brindan servicios web, y a su vez quieren brindar el servicio de un sistema web para facturar, entonces los suscritos tendran el sistema web a su disposicion para generar facturas y demas. De alli parte la idea de que cada suscriptor debe tener uns base de datos.

Comment: Entonces cada suscrito, creara usuarios para esa suscripción, guardar clientes y proveedores, productos o servicios, entre otros. Ejemplo: una empresa de lubricantes contrata para el sistema de facturación, tambien un supermercado, una farmacia, un restaurante. teniendo todos esos suscritos el sistema deberia guardar los archivos en una base de datos por suscriptor y asi solo generar consultas a la base de datos de ese suscriptor.

Comment: Ahi ya las cosas empiezan a sonar diferente. por ahi deberias tener una base maestra con esa informacion? y cuando el usuario se conecta tener esa informacion ya disponible? igual, con esa informacion, es una pregunta re valida.. te parece editar la pregunta y agregar todo eso ahi?

Comment: Si, debo tener una base de datos maestra con todos los suscritos, la cual llevara: Nombre, Apellido, I.D. personal, y el nombre de la base de datos(bduser) para que se conecte a esta para realizar los salvados de la información. Me ayudarias a modificar la pregunta? por favor